# Possible to override the text in a validation error dialog box?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form built out in HTML, and for sake of keeping things simple and to the point, I have the following (along with 3 other similar `<input>` radio buttons, wrapped in a `<form>` tag:

```
<input id="Q1_r1" name="Question_1" required="" type="radio" value="Very Bad"><label class="radio" for="Q1_r1"><span style="padding-left:30px; font-size:13px;">
```

So, when you try to submit this form without choosing a radio option, we get a validation error:

[image]

Totally expected - so the question I have is, is there any way to override the "cloud.chfsmail.ky.gov" in the alert box to something more user friendly?

Comment: I know it's not what you asked for, but building your own alerts it's the best way. I make my own for every client. It's really simple, just some js, position fixed and message, and you got it. If you need an example i can show you.

Comment: @MatiasCoco thank you! An example would be awesome if you could! mike@mikemarks.net is my email

Comment: I sent you the email!

Comment: @MatiasCoco thank you so much! Appreciate ya

Answer (score 1):

For posterity's sake, here's a simple example of how one might create a custom alert-popup to communicate sth. to the user (in this case that the form wont submit until all fields are filled out).

The key idea is having a dedicated container for your message, who's visibility you change when you want to say sth. Don't forget to hide it again!

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

form.onsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ([...form.querySelectorAll('input')].some(i => !i.value)) {
    overlay.textContent = 'All fields need filling out';
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(() => overlay.classList.remove('active'), 3000);
  }
};
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  right: 50vw;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: none;
}

#overlay.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input name="foo">
    <span>Foo</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="bar">
    <span>Bar</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="baz">
    <span>Baz</span>
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```